# List formatting inside Gutenberg block without using List block

Tags: list, formatting, toolbar, wordpress-gutenberg

I have been struggling to find a solution to what I thought would be a straightforward issue: **allowing list formatting in my custom Gutenberg blocks**.

**I do not want to use the default List block** because that means I have to convert ALL of my custom blocks into an Innerblock/Outerblock setup in order to use it. I simply want to enable list formatting in the toolbar, just like you would for bold/italic etc.

I have not been able to find an example of this being done anywhere.

I am looking for any insight/suggestions on how I might achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: The list formatting toolbar is part of the RichText component. Are you using a RichText component in your block?

Comment: We are in fact. I did actually get a response from plugin support on this here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-formatting-inside-gutenberg-block/#post-14897995

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand the ask. What do you mean by "list formatting"?